# how to create security while we connect to oracle database from sas

Tags: sas

```
 %let user=scott;
 %let password=tiger;

libname ora oracle user=&user password=&password;

 options mprint mlogic symbolgen;

 dm log 'clear';
```

in this way can we provide security to database?
so, i am trying to make security for my connection, if i clear my log that no one can see it.but once i close my sas section the library which i created will be vanished, so, can u please  help me to create permanent library in order to make sure there is a connection with oracle after the section has closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your libname statement to the autoexec.sas file.  Here is how SAS looks for that file if you need to create one.
http://support.sas.com/kb/19/244.html

You can encode the password so you do not have to store it as plain text.  Look at PROC PWENCODE -- http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/66817/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0dc6in0v7nfain1f2whl6f5x66p.htm

Comment: Note that encoded passwords aren't really secure if you are just going to leave them in code (or in logs) that others can read.  Anyone can copy paste your encoded password and use the encoded version to gain access as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure security of your oracle credentials is to use `dbprompt=yes` in the LIBNAME statement. In this case you don't need to include your username and password into the statement - they will be prompted (in pop-up window) each time the library is being assigned. Which of course not so convenient, especially if you want this library to be assigned for every session. But security is worth of some sacrifices, I think...

It will work for SAS Base interface, but not for Enterprise Guide (when SAS-server is on the same local machine that EG itself, which is almost always the case): http://support.sas.com/kb/7/980.html

In this situation you can create user prompts using EG functionality (Prompt Manager). These prompts will assign your login and password entered into prompt window to macro variables, which you can then reference to in the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: If your program isn't running in batch mode (ie. without human intervention) then this is probably your best bet.